# laravel 4 validation unique on two columns

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4

Hi I'm working on some validation in Laravel and I want to ensure that the field uid is unique with a project_id. For example my database table is as follows:

```
id | project_id | uid        |
1  | 3          | task_uid   |
2  | 4          | task_uid2  |
3  | 4          | task_uid   |
```

A uid can exist twice within a project_id but not if the project_id is the same.

I've tried the following;

```
public static $rules = array(
    'UID' => 'required|unique:uid,project_id'
);
```

However this hasn't worked and returns the following sql error;

```
"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'project.uid' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `uid` where `project_id` = task_uid)"
```

Any ideas how I may be able to check the tasks table to ensure that the project_id and uid are unique values??

Comment: That's interesting question !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

** PLEASE TAKE NOTE: This is for Laravel 4 **

The way unique works (In **laravel 4**):

```
unique:{tableName},{columnName}
```

Try

```
public static $rules = array(
    'UID' => 'required|unique:{tableName},uid|unique:{tableName},project_id'
);
```

** PLEASE TAKE NOTE: This is for Laravel 4 ****

Comment: this did not work to me. Please let me know if I need to write this as custom validation rule

Comment: i dont think this will work as it's not looking for the combined columns uniqueness but separate column uniqueness. As far as i can see you would have to create a custom validator which performs a query looking for a record where both columns match.

Comment: public function validateUniqueProjectUser($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
    {
        $inputs  = $validator->getData();
        $projectId = $inputs['project_id'];
        $numDupes = ProjectUser::where([
            'project_id' => $projectId,
            'uid' => $value
        ])->count();
        return ($numDupes > 0);
    }

AppServiceProvider:

Validator::extend('unique_security', 'App\Validators\CustomValidator@validateUniqueProjectUser');

Apply rule:

public static $rules = array(
    'UID' => 'required|unique_project_user'
);