# Laravel - Unique validation from two fields

Tags: php, validation, unique, laravel-5.5

I'm developing a project in Laravel, and I'm stuck. I have a model shown below with field `numero_factura` that has to be unique by `empresa`. I tried to do a validation to store an already created record like below, after execute `$validator->fails()` laravel says `The numero_factura has already been taken`.

How can I validate in order to `numero_factura` is excluded itself and so unique by `empresa_id` as well?

I really appreciate who can help me. :)

Model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyModel extends Model {

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'numero_factura', 'fecha', 'cantidad', 'comprobante', 'estado'
    ];

    public function empresa() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Empresa');
    }

}
```

Validation:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'numero_factura' => ['required', Rule::unique('facturas')->ignore($factura->id, 'numero_factura')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        return $query->where('empresa_id', $request->session()->get('empresa_id'));
    })],
]);
```

Comment: check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855787/laravel-validation-unique-on-two-columns